# How can I make my absolute bottom container stay still when zooming?

Tags: html, css, layout, positioning, absolute

I was wondering how I can stop this bottom text from moving around when someone zooms in or out. The rest of the page so far stays still but because I have had to use position:absolute to make this particular section stay at the bottom of another div (content), it now moves.

```
#content {
border: 2px solid;
border-radius: 10px;
border-color:#ffffff;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #999999;
}

#bottomsectioncontainer {
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
padding-left:200px;
padding-right:275px;
}
```

```
<div id="container2" style="width:1300px; height;975px; margin:auto">

<div id="content" style="background-color:#ffffff; height:975px";>

<!---content--->

<div id="bottomsectioncontainer" style="height: 5px; margin:auto;">


<div id="bottom1" style="width: 250px; float:left">


<h4 class="h4"> Example </h4>
<p class=bottompara>One thing <br>
Two Thing<br>
Three thing<br>
Four Thing<br>
Five Thing<br>
</p>

</div>


<div id="bottom2" style="width: 250px;float:left">

<h4 class="h4"> Example </h4>
<p class=bottompara>One thing <br>
Two Thing<br>
Three thing<br>
Four Thing<br>
Five Thing<br>
</p>


</div>

<div id="bottom3" style="width: 250px; float:left;">

<h4 class="h4"> Example </h4>
<p class="bottompara">One thing <br>
Two Thing<br>
Three thing<br>
Four Thing<br>
Five Thing<br>
</p>


</div>

</div>
</div>



</body>

</html>
```

http://tinypic.com/r/wwi35l/8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
position:relative;
```

in `#content` it will fix that problem

and also remove `height:5px` from bottomcontainer

Comment: Okay thanks man that made the text stop moving while zoomed, but now unfortunately it has been pushed out of the #content box altogether and also the example3 section has moved to underneath the example1 section, in case you didn't notice I'm quite the novice.

Comment: <div id="bottomsectioncontainer" style="height: 5px; margin:auto;">

remove height:5px from this

Answer (score 0):

```
#content {
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks man that made the text stop moving while zoomed, but now unfortunately it has been pushed out of the #content box altogether and also the example3 section has moved to underneath the example1 section, in case you didn't notice I'm quite the novice